Struct package adds 2 more bytes to end. Python
When I'm packing my datas via struct and sending it over serial it gives me 80 bytes instead of 78 bytes. Also struct.calcsize('6B17f4B') returns me 80 but that gave me a little confusion because when calculated 6B = 6 + 17F = 68 (17 *4) + 4B = 4 so it needs to be 78 Bytes when summed.
This is my code to send over serial
    def crc(self, byte_values, float_values):
        float_bytes = struct.pack('17f', *float_values)
        # Include only the float bytes in the checksum calculation, as per your comment
        checksum = sum(float_bytes) % 256
        return checksum
      
    def sendData(self):
        self.takimid = 0x1f
        byte_values = (255, 255, 84, 82, self.takimid, 31)  # Starting byte values

        float_values = (self.irtifa, self.roketgpsirtifa, self.enlem, self.boylam, 
                        0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, self.gx, self.gy, self.gz,
                        self.ax, self.ay, self.az, self.rotz)  


        checksum = self.crc(byte_values, float_values)


        ending_bytes = (31, checksum, 13, 10)
        

        data = struct.pack('6B17f4B', *(byte_values + float_values + ending_bytes))

        try:
            if not self.ser.is_open:
                self.ser.open()
            self.ser.write(data)
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            self.error_signal.emit(f"Serial error: {e}")
        
        self.packet_counter += 1 
        if self.packet_counter == 255:
            self.packet_counter = 0

As I told, I tried to send 78Byte data pack but I recieve 80 Bytes and calcsize returns 80 on the package

Floats are aligned to 4-byte boundaries. So there are 2 bytes of padding between 6B and 17f.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment for how you can override this.

Thanks to all of you for helping. It worked I didn't know about that.
